# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

this is the DAO method i have to retrieve the list of students from DB and on RunTime it says -

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"

which is driving me crazy. Can anyone please tell me what i might have missed?

```
public List<Student> getStudentsByIds(List<Integer> studentIds) {
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(getSessionFactory(), true);
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM students s WHERE s.id IN (:studentIds)");
    query.setParameterList("studentIds", studentIds);
    return query.list();
}
```

Comment: If you print your "studentIds" list what do you get? are you sure it isn't wrapping an additional ")" inside the SQL?

Comment: I get list of Integers. Yeah, I'm sure its not wrapping

Comment: Shouldn't you use something like `id = ANY(:studentIds)` since you are providing an array

Comment: Have you tried using an array instead of a list?

Comment: Changing SQLQuery query = .... to Query query = .... made the error go away. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 13):

Probably `studentIds` is an empty list and postgres does not accept 
empty IN clause in generated code

```
select 
...
where
    students.id in (

    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue recently. So as I got from docs psql can't handle empty lists in `IN/NOT IN (:someEmptyList)` statements cause criteriaBuilder adds empty curly braces into final sql query: `(in ())`

Imho the easiest solution will be just to check for empty list and return empty result list back.

Or use more advanced tools if u have complex query and u really need it => https://marcelothebuilder.github.io/java/jpa/2017/09/11/jpa-post.html