# JAVA ERROR in SQL: syntax error at or near "(" Position: 26

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am getting this error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
  Position: 26
```

when I try use following method

**Repository**

```
@Query(value = "select new AgendamentoDTO(a.id, a.data, s.nome, p.nome, pro.nome) " + "from agendamento a " + "join pacientes p on p.id = a.paciente_id " + "join profissionais pro on pro.id = a.profissional_id " + "join servico s on s.id = a.servico_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<AgendamentoDTO> agendamentos3();
```

**DTO**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AgendamentoDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String data;
    private String servico;
    private String paciente;
    private String profissional;

    public AgendamentoDTO(Integer id, String paciente, String data, String profissional, String servico) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
        this.servico = servico;
        this.paciente = paciente;
        this.profissional = profissional;
    }
}
```

SpringData - 2.7.0

Database - PostgreSQL

Comment: Isn't the point of `nativeQuery = true` that the query should be just plain SQL? If so, "select new AgendamentoDTO(a.id, a.data, s.nome, p.nome, pro.nome)" doesn't look appropriate to me.

Comment: Looks like your list is empty. check the similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877775/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-error-syntax-error-at-or-near

Comment: Constructing a DTO onl works in JPQL not in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Works when I Change to JPQL.

```
@Query(value = "select new com.tcc.tccbackend.dtos.AgendamentoDTO(a.id, a.data, s.nome, p.nome, pro.nome) " + "from Agendamento a " + "join Paciente p on p.id = a.id " + "join Profissional pro on pro.id = a.id " + "join Servico s on s.id = a.id")
    List<AgendamentoDTO> agendamentos3();
```